# User input for triangles in python

Tags: python

I would like to create a triangle and take user input from the user. I have already created the function for creating triangles.

Function:

```
def triangle(rows):
    PrintingList = list()
    for rownum in range (rows ):     
        PrintingList.append([])
        for iteration in range (rownum):
            newValue = raw_input()
            PrintingList[rownum].append(newValue)
```

But this takes input in this way..

```
3 
7
4
2 
4 
6
8 
5 
9 
3
```

I need it to take a input like this:

```
3 
7 4
2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

How do it change it to take input in this way? need some guidance on this...

Comment: seems like a trick question in which the real goal is to flatten the input list back to the accepted input and continue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for rownum in range (rows ):     
    PrintingList.append([])
    newValues = raw_input().strip().split()
    PrintingList[rownum] += newValues
```

I don't see here if you need or not to convert input from strings to ints.. But if you need, this will look like

```
for rownum in range (rows ):     
    PrintingList.append([])
    newValues = map(int, raw_input().strip().split())
    PrintingList[rownum] += newValues
```